# Suggestion on how to improve a question

Tags: support

I'm not an english native speaker and I'm still studying Machine Learning, could you revise my question and tell me if it's clear what I'm asking? I would really appreciate a lot.

[Which is the format required for a partitioning algorithm?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22818/which-is-the-format-required-for-a-partitioning-algorithm)

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't seem at all specific to data science, so I think the first step is to post it on a more appropriate forum.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the site.

As Sean Owen said, this question does not look on-topic in this site, as it has nothing to do with DataScience. The 3 sites which come up to my mind where this can be on-topic are:

1. Software Engineering
2. Stack Overflow
3. Computer Science

But, I am not sure about where this would make a good fit. So, you are better off asking in the [Meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) with the [site-recommendation](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) and [support](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support) tags.

Comment: Wait a second.. it's about clustering / partitioning.. have you read it to the end? I've a list of interconnected elements listed in two columns.. I want to divide them in groups of strongly interconnected elements.. I cannot use machine learning to do that?

Comment: @Revious I did read it completely. Your question is very unclear. What are you trying to achieve?  What have you tried so far?.  Possible to make the exact question a bit more to-the-point?

Comment: I've modified it. Can you have a look? Should I get rid of the first part?

Comment: The latest additions still don't look much like a data science problem, but something more along the lines of data-oriented development, which we do not address here.

Comment: @E_net4: thanks, so data clustering is not related to data science unless it's probabilistic? (it's not a provocation)